# I am trying to build a redis nodeJS cache system

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, redis

Each time i try to run my code for my redis-nodeJS system, I am given this error for one of the functions.

```
> events.js: 174
>       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>       ^
> 
> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
>     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net .js : 1280:14)
>     at listenInCluster (net .js :1328:12)
>     at Server.listen (net. js : 1415 :7)
>     at Function.listen (/home/ richu biju /node_modules/express/lib/application . js :618:24)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ richubiju /Downloads/ index8. js: 57: 5)
>     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs /loader . js :778:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/ cjs / loader.js:789:10)
>     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
>     at try Module Load (internal/modules/cjs /loader . js :593:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3) Emitted 'error' event at:
>     at emit ErrorNT (net .js :1307:8)
>     at process._tick Callback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
>     at Function.Module. run Main (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
>     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
>     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Comment: Judging by error message - something is already listening port 5000 (on which, I presume, you're trying to start an express server). It may be another app, or may be your previous attempts to start this app, which ended up in crash and left dangling nodejs process.

Comment: Same 5000 port is used by other process.A quick workaround is to use a different port instead of 5000. Also I hope you are running express server and redis in different ports

Answer (score 0):

This means you or another process on your computer are already using port 5000. I'm not sure which one it is but you can try killing the port. Or a better alternative is to use another port to listen on.